# Android Auto Music app no sound,MediaPlayer callback shows play success

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-auto, google-music

I developed a music app to support Android Auto, MediaPlayer call back shows already playing, but no sound.
Then I found that if I choose Google Music to play a song first, then I switch to my app, everything runs perfectly.
Is there anything I did wrong or it is Android Auto's bug???

Comment: The question seems that there is an Android auto's big but I recommend you to test in other devices too..

Comment: problem solved , request audio focus first

Comment: @UmangBurman audio focus problem, request focus first solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

problem solved , request audio focus first